# How to dump data from one table and insert to another

Tags: mysql, dump

I have two databases. I want to dump data from one table in 1st database and insert to another table with an another name in 2nd database.
So I have DB1 that has tables tbl1 and tabl2, and DB2 that has tables tbl3 and tbl4. I know that tabl1 and tabl3 have the same structure. How to copy data from one to another by using mysqldump command?
I've tried to do this, but it's not work.

```
mysqldump --user root --password=password --no-create-info DB1 tbl1 > c:/dump.sql
mysql --user root --password=password DB2 tbl3 < c:/dump.sql
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not going to work due to different table name

if both database are sitting in the same server using the same daemon, you can directly

```
insert into DB2.tbl3 select * from DB1.tbl1;
```

if tbl1 is not existing in DB2,
pseudo code for this :

```
# import as tbl1 from DB1 into tbl1 in DB2
mysqldump DB1 tbl1 | mysql DB2

# then rename tbl1 in DB2 to tbl3
mysql DB2 -N <<< "rename table tbl1 to tbl3"
```

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this old post, Can you please tell me, which approach is better- performance wise, `insert into tbl3` or taking a dump and restoring from it in new table, considering my table has `10 crore(100 million)` entries.

Comment: do a dump, and reinsert will be better. Or set up a replication.

Answer (score 3):

I am using in a linux shell command line

```
mysqldump --user=username --password=xxxx dbname | mysql --host=remotehost.com --user=username --password=xxxx -C dname
```

this transfers it from the local host to a remote host, the whole database.

Comment: When I run this command(mysqldump --user=root --password=password DB1 tbl1 | mysql --user=root --password=password -C DB2 tbl3) in says: "Got err no 22 on write".

Comment: Are you sure that the username/password combination has sufficient rights to do this on both sides?

Comment: worked for me. @Alexandor did not define remote hostname for `mysql`

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to also copy the contents of the table you can do:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table_name` LIKE `old_table_name`;
INSERT INTO `new_table_name` SELECT * FROM `old_table_name`;
```

If you have to copy table from one database to another database then use following

```
 CREATE TABLE `db1.new_table_name` LIKE `db2.old_table_name`;
 INSERT INTO `db1.new_table_name` SELECT * FROM `db2.old_table_name`;
```

It works for me as dumping single table and importing was throwing syntax error with MariaDB